# How to pass string which includes comma in sql insert query PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am firing an insert query in database which is like below:

```
$upd_noti = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE tbl_notification SET message=:msg,datetime=:date,userto=:part_reg_id,userfrom=:reg_id,post_id=:postid,status=:status,noti_read=:notiread,noti_type=:notitype,msg_type=:msgtype WHERE tms_id=:tmsid AND userto=:to AND userfrom=:from AND noti_type=:type");

    $upd_noti->execute(array(':msg'=>$msgsdf,':date'=>$todateghfd1,':part_reg_id'=>$partner_reg_id,':reg_id'=>$reg_id,':postid'=>$postid1,':status'=>'unread',':notiread'=>'false',':notitype'=>'partner',':msgtype'=>'accept request',':tmsid'=>$tms_id,':to'=>$reg_id,':from'=>$partner_reg_id,':type'=>'partner'));
```

array value i am passing:

```
Array ( [:msg] => has accepted your request to play American Football,Athletics,Australian Rules,Badminton,Basketball,Camogie,Cricket,Cycling,Darts,Football,Gaelic Football,Golf,Hockey,Hurling,Judo,Kick Boxing,Korfball,Lacrosse,Netball,Rugby League,Rugby Union,Running,Sailing,Softball,Squash,Swimming,Table Tennis,Tag Rugby,Tennis,Touch Rugby,Triathlon,Volleyball, [:date] => 2017-07-20 12:47:29 [:part_reg_id] => 10 [:reg_id] => 1 [:postid] => 1080 [:status] => unread [:notiread] => false [:notitype] => partner [:msgtype] => accept request [:tmsid] => 19 [:to] => 1 [:from] => 10 [:type] => partner )
```

Now my main problem is I am getting result as below:

```
UPDATE tbl_notification SET message=Football,Badminton,Cricket,Table Tennis,Tennis,Volleyball,datetime=2017-07-20 11:04:47,userto=4,userfrom=3,post_id=4326,status=unread,noti_read=false,noti_type=partner,msg_type=accept partner WHERE tms_id=2
```

While I want an output of the query like below:

```
UPDATE tbl_notification SET message='Football,Badminton,Cricket,Table Tennis,Tennis,Volleyball',datetime='2017-07-20 11:04:47',userto='4',userfrom='3',post_id='4326',status='unread',noti_read='false',noti_type='partner',msg_type='accept partner' WHERE tms_id='2'
```

I basically not able to add quotation mark (') around the string which i am passing in the placeholder as it has commas (,).

Comment: I don't understand your question. How could your query produce the result you're getting? You're not showing us the full code or telling us the full story.

Comment: you also should be normalizing your db.

Comment: Last time we got the same problem we just replace prepared statement for raw sql query generation on application side (yes, i know it is bad).

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have written the PDO queries i am firing.

Comment: I just want to know the format of add ' ' around the values i am passing.

Comment: " problem is I am getting result as below:" WHERE did you get that result? Mysql query log? your query is also missing the ' ' around the datetime for example. Do you really have a problem, or did you try to let php show you the query you _think_ you generated?

Comment: this is not about the resposne i am getting from where, i am firing a query with message=Football,Badminton,Cricket,Table Tennis,Tennis,Volleyball,datetime  but i have to fire the query with message='Football,Badminton,Cricket,Table Tennis,Tennis,Volleyball,datetime'

Comment: 'Football,Badminton,Cricket,Table Tennis,Tennis,Volleyball,datetime' this is a single string which suppose to be added in 1 column

Comment: i have already added my prepare and execute statements

Comment: what is the error message you get? And where did you get the actually executed query (the one with values) from?"

Comment: as this is pdo I am not getting the exact query but printed the array list i am passing,

Comment: @IvoP  updated my question to show the array result.

Comment: Basically I am not getting any query but the update query dont fire on my mysql table

Comment: Where is the part "has accepted your request" gone in the query. And if the query cannot be executed on your database, it will generate an error message. `echo $upd_noti->error(); ` after executing

Comment: @IvoP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::error()

Comment: sorry: `$upd_noti->errorInfo()[2]; ` is should be.

Comment: or for older php: `$arr = $upd_noti->errorInfo();  echo $arr[2];`

Comment: @user3657517 did you find out the real error already?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$upd_noti->execute(array(':msg'=>"'".$msgsdf."'",':date'=>$todateghfd1,':part_reg_id'
             =>$partner_reg_id,':reg_id'=>$reg_id,':postid'=>$postid1,':status'=>'unread',
              ':notiread'=>'false',':notitype'=>'partner',':msgtype'=>'accept 
              request',':tmsid'=>$tms_id,':to'=>$reg_id,':from'=>$partner_reg_id,':type'=>'
              partner'));
```

Just replace `':msg'=>$msgsdf` with `':msg'=>"'".$msgsdf."'"`

It will work for you.

Comment: the whole point of the prepared statements is, that those quotes are added automatically and in a safe way. Do not add them manually.

Comment: but here those quotes are not adding so you can do this manually that the issue with that?